# SharePoint 2013 My Tasks WebPart - update on loading

Tags: my-site, tasks

I created a custom page on MySites (installed with FeatureStapling) on that page the I added a View-WebPart for "My Tasks", which re-uses the List displayed in the "My Tasks"-Page of the MySite.

The WebPart displays correctly, however it does not reload the tasks from my custom page. When I navigate to "My Tasks" the tasks are reloaded and then also displayed on my custom page.

Anyone have an idea how I can make the "My Tasks" webpart on my custom page reload the tasks that are assigned to me?

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.

The MyTasks WebPart has 2 Properties (see ToolPart "Miscellaneous"):

- ShowRefreshStatus
- ShowViewSelector

When enabling the `ShowRefreshStatus`, the WebPart gets updated.